# ant loadfile task does not work with czech characters given in xml file

Tags: xml, utf-8, ant

I have below info.xml file which uses Czech character for the node company:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Candidates>
    <name>Arvind Kumar</name>
    <company>ěčš</company>
</Candidates>
```

I have below build.xml file to read info.xml file and display content of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Check" default="">
    <xmlproperty file="info.xml" collapseAttributes="true"/>
    <echo file="output.txt" append="false">${Candidates.company}</echo>
</project>
```

After running ant on windows 7, I get following output in output.txt which shows incorrect value of 'company':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Candidates>
    <name>Arvind Kumar</name>
    <company>??š</company>
</Candidates>
```

I tried following another build.xml to use ant loadfile task with encoding but this did not help also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Check" default="">
    <loadfile encoding="utf-8" srcFile="info.xml" property="encoded_file"/>
    <echo file="output.txt" append="false">${encoded_file}</echo>
</project>
```

Please let me know how to use ant task which can read and display correctly Czech characters present in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with ant. How the characters are displayed is dependent upon the program you use to view the info. e.g. If you are displaying the UTF-8 characters on Windows command prompt then it'll not display correctly as it does not have UTF-8 support. (There might be settings to change it but by default it doesn't). If you are putting it in a file then the viewer you use to display the file should support the UTF-8 encoding.

If you do the same thing on a console with UTF-8 support e.g. kconsole (part of KDE) running Bash on Linux which does have UTF-8, then it displays the text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possibilities: either the characters are wrongly encoded in the input, or they are being displayed incorrectly when you view the output (as suggested by @Jignesh).

To check that the characters in the input are correct, try using an XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon and running the XPath 2.0 expression

```
string-to-codepoints(//city)
```

This will give you the decimal values of the Unicode codepoints corresponding to the characters in the city name - for example ü should be 252. If it's wrong, then the actual encoding of the input XML doesn't match the declared encoding, so the character has been misread. If it's correct, then the Ant task / transformation is probably working OK and the problem is downstream, and you need to look more carefully at how the output file is being processed/displayed.

Answer (score 0):

While Loading you are using encoding, however while Reading you are not using encoding. 
Change the below line:

```
<echo file="output.txt" append="false">${encoded_file}</echo>
```

TO:

```
<echo encoding=:UTF-8" file="output.txt" append="false">${encoded_file}
 </echo>.
```

This should solve the problem.

Also your first XML file should be:

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Check" default="">
 <xmlproperty file="test.xml" collapseAttributes="true"/>
 <echo encoding="utf-8" file="output.xml" 
        append="false">${Candidates.company}</echo>
</project>
```